# ArgumentError: Invalid option: copyright When precompiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I just upgraded Uglier to 4.1.6 it was very outdated, but after trying to precompile my assets for production I got this error:

```
ArgumentError: Invalid option: copyright
```

I thought it could be because of my sprockets, but I found that upgrading sprockets may be complicated and I don't want to break anything, so maybe thought that upgrading sprockets would not be necessary.

My sprockets version is

```
sprockets ~> 3.4.0
sprockets-rails ~> 2.3.3
```

My Rails version is `4.2.5` and my previous version of uglifier was `1.3.0` (very outdated) lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that somewhere in your rails env where you instantiate uglifier you have a copyright option key set. 
What I mean is - try searching for something like this:

```
...
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(
   :copyright => false, # <--- this
   :mangle => true,
...
```

You can delete that option key unless you really need it and then try precompiling again to see whether this resolves your issue...

Answer (score 0):

For people that comes here with the same problem, downgrade uglifer to 3.2 fixes the problem for me:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.2'
```

Option dropped in uglifier 4:
https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-2-december-2017

Comment: Did you mean downgrade uglifier? That worked for me as well (not sprockets but uglifier)